# apache cassandra 3.9 - Enabling security

Tags: cassandra, datastax

we are trying to add a node to the existing ring where in security is enabled and default cassandra user is made nonsuper. Also, alerted keyspace to networktopology with replication = no.of nodes. The ring is currently on AWS.

Once the new node joins the cluster, only user we see is nonsuper cassandra user. we are pretty much lokced out of the cluster. However, once we remove the newly joined node, all the security that we had before comes back.

Are there any best practices that we need to follow to enable security in 3.9?

Thanks in advance for helping me out on this.!!

Comment: Was your cluster upgraded to 3.9 or was it initialized with this version?

Comment: It is initialized with this version